# Score of Area 51 not showing

Tags: bug, stack-exchange-button, communities-list

I think Area 51 is a site of Stack Exchange, so why does the score of Area 51 not show my score here?

[image: area 51]

But it is showing it here:

[image: area 51]

Comment: mmm @ShadowWizard i think we share a part but i ask why the score is not show, i dont ask about notification